# Jackson allow unquoted control chars disadvantages

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson-modules

Hi I use spring web and I need to send newline characters in my string by default I got 400 bad request.When I change allow-unquoted-control-chars parameter that time my request passed successfully

```
spring.jackson.parser.allow-unquoted-control-chars=true
```

in jackson release notes,I see this is non standard.My question is what is the correct way to pass unquoted chars like new line?If I change this parameter is there any security or another issue I can face?Is there any disadvantage to change this parameter

```
Since JSON specification requires quoting for all control characters, this is a non-standard feature, and as such disabled by default.
```